# Set Default Value On Quick Create Form

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have two sub grids that display data from the same entity on a form.

When a quick create form is loaded I want to set a default value based on the sub grid that triggered

Eg. Set source field to Sub Grid 1 or Sub Grid 2.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you talking about mapping attributes in entity relationship?

Comment: @ArunVinoth I don't think this could be done via entity relationships because the OP says that both sub-grids show the same entity. Does anyone know if a subgrid can add a parameter to the querystring? That would be the path I'd investigate

Comment: @jasonscript I am wondering the same thing. Can a parameter some how be passed to the quick create form.

Answer (score 0):

This is not feasible, atleast in a supported way. In unsupported, we can try to invoke some additional param in addition to OOB QV form call using DOM ( I never tried this )

This kinda requirement is cyclic, you need a field to filter the view for subgrid, same time you need to get that field value from some hidden field or query string.

But we achieved something similar, in our case, we identified the **type** of document picklist (viz Required/Supporting doc which will filter the records for 2 subgrids of same entity) based on another **doc category** lookup field selected in the QV form (this field is a config entity which will have **category** & **type** mapped).

This mapping helped us to decide. If you don't have any deciding field, try to identify or introduce one.